# Excel Graph: X,Y points in alternating columns, different series per row

Tags: excel, graph, scatter-plot

We receive a large CSV data file where each row contains a few columns of metadata and then an arbitrary length sequence of X,Y point values in alternating columns.  Different rows may contain different numbers of points.  The actual data may contain hundreds of rows, each with many X,Y values (possibly a couple of thousand points).

The format of this data file is not within our control.

As a simple sample for illustration:

```
Series 1,ID142,2,45,7,21,1,65.5,14,22
Series 2,ID082,11,23,6,15,3,29,13,84,9,78,42,45,15,17
```

The above example would represent two series: Series 1 with points (2,45), (7,21), (1,65.5), (14,22), and Series 2 with points (11,23), (6,15), (3,29), (13,84), (9,78), (42,45), (15,17).

The most useful way to analyze this data would be multiple series in a scatter plot in Excel.  An engineer might be interested in seeing a scatter-plot with row 1 data as series 1 and row 58 data as series 2.  That might lead to wanting to see a plot of row 8 and row 97.  So, it would not be realistic to have a complicated process to reformat the data depending on the rows of interest.

Is there a way to easily build Excel scatter-plots with multiple series from data where each series is represented by a single row with the multiple X and Y values all in that row in alternating columns (as the sample above)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the offset function. You can open a new sheet and write this in the first cell A1, press control+ shift+ enter
 and drag the formula across the columns
=OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,M,0,1,100) 
similarly do this in A2 and drag it across
=OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,N,0,1,100) 
This would return the Mth row from top in sheet 1 completely into first row, and Nth row into the second row. You can give reference to M and N values in different cells to make it dynamic.